# How to Loop a Function in Python Without a Clear Variable

Tags: python, loops, random

Below is code that correctly outputs a random password based on the sequence, using multiple for loops. I want to loop the function 10 times to output 10 passwords, but I can't seem to figure out what variable to loop in this case.

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K','L','M','N','O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
num_letters= random.randint(3, 6)
num_numbers = random.randint(1, 4)
num_symbols = (10 - num_letters - num_numbers)
print(f'Your requested {num_letters} letters, {num_numbers} numbers, and {num_symbols} symbols:')
password_list = []
for num in range(num_letters):
`letter = random.choice(letters)`    
`password_list.append(letter)`
for num in range(num_numbers):
`number = random.choice(numbers)`
`password_list.append(number)`
for num in range(num_symbols):
`symbol = random.choice(symbols)`
`password_list.append(symbol)`
random.shuffle(password_list)
password = ''   

for char in password_list:
`password = password + char`

print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K','L','M','N','O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

def generator():
    print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
    num_letters= random.randint(3, 6)
    num_numbers = random.randint(1, 4)
    num_symbols = (10 - num_letters - num_numbers)
    print(f'Your requested {num_letters} letters, {num_numbers} numbers, and {num_symbols} symbols:')
    password_list = []
    for num in range(num_letters):
        letter = random.choice(letters)
        password_list.append(letter)
    for num in range(num_numbers):
        number = random.choice(numbers)
        password_list.append(number)
    for num in range(num_symbols):
        symbol = random.choice(symbols)
        password_list.append(symbol)
    random.shuffle(password_list)
    password = ''   

    for char in password_list:
        password = password + char
    print(password)
    return password

print([generator() for i in range(10)])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this generator in a function!

As such I have a main function to run the program and ask how many times you would like to iterate the password generator function.

```
import random

def main():

    print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
    val = input("Enter number of passwords you want to generate: ")
    iterate = int(val)
    #print("Generated passwords: ")

    for i in range(iterate):
        passwordGenerator()

def passwordGenerator():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K','L','M','N','O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']
    
    num_letters= random.randint(3, 6)
    num_numbers = random.randint(1, 4)
    num_symbols = ((10 - num_letters - num_numbers) + 1) 
    print(f'Your requested {num_letters} letters, {num_numbers} numbers, and {num_symbols} symbols:')
    password_list = []
    for num in range(num_letters):
        letter = random.choice(letters)
        password_list.append(letter)

    for num in range(num_numbers):
        number = random.choice(numbers)
        password_list.append(number)
    for num in range(num_symbols):
        symbol = random.choice(symbols)
        password_list.append(symbol)
        random.shuffle(password_list)
        password = ''   

    for char in password_list:
        password = password + char

    print(password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!
Enter number of passwords you want to generate: 3
Your requested 3 letters, 3 numbers, and 5 symbols:
(7I3$7&%)vm
Your requested 4 letters, 1 numbers, and 6 symbols:
&*PV#6u#N&)
Your requested 3 letters, 2 numbers, and 6 symbols:
8#*)8!!lt)h
```

Answer (score 0):

- I put all your loops in the function to make your code easy to read and undrestand
- `no_passwords = 10` i make new variable to specify the number of passwords you want
- `for _ in range(no_passwords): generat_password()` make loop run in range of the variable we made called `no_passwords` and each time the code will call the function `generat_password()` to generate a new password

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K','L','M','N','O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

def generat_password():
    password_list = []

    for num in range(num_letters):
        letter = random.choice(letters)
        password_list.append(letter)

    for num in range(num_numbers):
        number = random.choice(numbers)
        password_list.append(number)

    for num in range(num_symbols):
        symbol = random.choice(symbols)
        password_list.append(symbol)

    random.shuffle(password_list)
    password = ''

    for char in password_list:
        password = password + char

    print(password)


print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
num_letters= random.randint(3, 6)
num_numbers = random.randint(1, 4)
num_symbols = (10 - num_letters - num_numbers)
no_passwords = 10
print(f'Your requested {num_letters} letters, {num_numbers} numbers, and {num_symbols} symbols:')

for _ in range(no_passwords):
    generat_password()
```